# Sequelize: joining table on a subquery

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

I am trying to join a table on a subquery, but I don't know how to express it using Sequelize ORM. This is the raw SQL I want to run:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_a a
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT * FROM table_b b WHERE col = VAL) ON a.id = b.id;
```

I tried

```
A.findAll({
    include: [
        {
            model: B,
            where: { col: val },
        }
    ]
}).then(...);
```

but that doesn't get me the query I want. Instead it changes the `join` to an `INNER JOIN`, and joins on `col = VALUE` instead. Is there a way to do a join on the result of a subquery? I am using Postgres if it matters.

Update: After making the following change, the resulting query now uses a LEFT OUTER JOIN as expected:

```
include: [
    {
        model: B,
        where: { col: val },
        required: false,
    }
]
```

However, it is still joining on col = VALUE, the generated query looks like:

```
SELECT * FROM table_a a 
LEFT OUTER JOIN table_b b ON a.id = b.id AND b.col = VALUE;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These 2 queries ARE functionally equivalent:

```
SELECT * FROM table_a a
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT * FROM table_b b WHERE col = VAL) ON a.id = b.id;

SELECT * FROM table_a a 
LEFT OUTER JOIN table_b b ON a.id = b.id AND b.col = VALUE;
```

There is NO ADVANTAGE from the first one whatsoever. So, if the first one provides the wanted results, so should the second one.

Comment: there are differences if one need to limit the many records in table_b to one and sorted

Comment: Yes, but that's not this question.